# Match a word from beginning of line in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have following output from a command:

```
NAME         PLATFORM   STATUS
----         --         ------
XAB           Windows    Yes
ABB          Windows    Yes
AB           Windows    No
ABAB        Windows    Yes
```

Where name column have unique strings.

I want to find out if an input string exists in the name column such that it exactly matches the input. For e.g. If I am searching for A or B, it will return false, AB will return true.

I have tried following which returns false:

```
Arrays.stream(str.split("\n"))
            .filter(line -> line.matches("^AB "))
            .findFirst()
            .isPresent()
```

`string.contains()` doesn't seems to be suitable as it will not do strict pattern check.

Can you guys suggest a proper one line solution for this using streams? Thanks.

Comment: why can't you simply use `name.equals("AB")` ? If you need to look for the beginning of the string, then use `name.startsWith("AB")`

Comment: `.filter(line -> line.matches("AB .*"))`

Comment: Why not `.filter(line -> line.startsWith("AB"))` or `line.startsWith("AB ")`??

Comment: `line.startsWith("AB")` as mentioned seems the easiest solution, no need for a stream.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew because `line.startsWith("A")` will match also, and it seems the OP does not what that

Comment: And a better way to check that any stream element meets a predicate: `Arrays.stream(s.split("\n")).anyMatch(line -> line.startsWith("AB"))`

Comment: you could use just a `regex` like `^YourStringHere$`, or `equals`, right?

Comment: `.startsWith()` will match ABAB also. I don't want that.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava `line.matches("AB .*")` works.

Comment: again, why not use `equals`?

Comment: @Eugene I don't want to split every line and then call `equals`.

Comment: @S.K. `.startsWith("AB ")` won't match any `ABAB`. It is equal to `line.matches("AB .*")`.

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense for the regex to be `AB\\s+.*`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `.startsWith("AB ")` is also correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a line starts with a value you may use `String#startsWith`:

```
line.startsWith("AB ")
```

or, if you plan to use a regex, use `.matches` keeping in mind it must match the whole line (thus, adding `.*` is necessary as it will match any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible):

```
line.matches("AB .*")
```